# How do I connect with my friends worlds without the same wifi

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friend and I have been trying to connect forever. We don't have the same Wifi, it should still work though correct? That is, if we aren't connected to the same local Wifi network, is it possible for us to play in the same world together?

Comment: I assume you're talking about Pocket Edition?

Answer (score 1):

The multiplayer on MCPE is limited to the same WiFi network, equivalent to opening to LAN. The only way around this is Minecraft Realms or hosting your own MCPE server.